# Different ports in WSO2 AS

Tags: server, wso2, tomcat7, wso2-as

Is there any way to configure WSO2 AS to deploy applications in different ports?

For Example:

In the list of applications when I click in "Go to URL" is redirected to host:8080/app1

but I'd like when I click "Go to URL" in a app, this one is redirected to host:8080/app1 and another one to host:8081/app2

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK you can't change the port for a particular app. But instead you can use virtual host concept to achieve some what similar behavior. Refer to WSO2 documentation for more details on this.
https://docs.wso2.com/display/AS530/Setting+up+Virtual+Hosts